# How can I make the "dot" and "comma" characters to both function the same way in TextBox without giving error?

Tags: c#

I want to make "." and "," to both work as decimal numbers. My problem is that by default on my computer it is "."(23.33 works) and it does error when i try putting "," (23,33). How can I make it work.

```
private static Double SolveExpression(String expression)
{
    char uiSep = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0];
    expression = expression.Replace('.', uiSep);
    expression = expression.Replace(',', uiSep);
    if (expression.StartsWith("("))
    {
        int opening_brackets = 1, closing_brackets = 0, current_symbol = 1;
        while (opening_brackets != closing_brackets)
        {
            if (expression[current_symbol] == '(')
                opening_brackets++;
            else if (expression[current_symbol] == ')')
                closing_brackets++;

            current_symbol++;
        }
        String expr = expression.Substring(1, current_symbol - 2);
        expression = expression.Remove(0, current_symbol);

        Match operation = Regex.Match(expression, @"^[\+\-\*\/]");
        if (operation.Success)
        {
            expression = expression.Remove(0, operation.Value.Length);
            switch (operation.Value)
            {
                case "+":
                    {
                        return SolveExpression(expr) + SolveExpression(expression);
                    }
                case "-":
                    {
                        return SolveExpression(expr) - SolveExpression(expression);
                    }
                case "*":
                    {
                        return SolveExpression(expr) * SolveExpression(expression);
                    }
                case "/":
                    {
                        return SolveExpression(expr) / SolveExpression(expression);
                    }
            }
        }
        else
            return SolveExpression(expr);
    }

    Match constant = Regex.Match(expression, @"(^-*\d+)((\.|\,)(\d+))?");
    if (constant.Success)
    {
        expression = expression.Remove(0, constant.Value.Length);

        Match operation = Regex.Match(expression, @"^[\+\-\*\/]");
        if (operation.Success)
        {
            expression = expression.Remove(0, operation.Value.Length);
            switch (operation.Value)
            {
                case "+":
                    {
                        return Double.Parse(constant.Value) + SolveExpression(expression);
                    }
                case "-":
                    {
                        return Double.Parse(constant.Value) - SolveExpression(expression);
                    }
                case "*":
                    {
                        return Double.Parse(constant.Value) * SolveExpression(expression);
                    }
                case "/":
                    {
                        return Double.Parse(constant.Value) / SolveExpression(expression);
                    }
            }
        }
        else
            return Double.Parse(constant.Value);
    }
    else
        //throw new Exception("Invalid Expression");
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered invalid expression! Revise and try again", "Something went wrong", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please define `it doesn't work`. Is the textbox in HTML (web app) or WInforms or WPF or some other technology?

Comment: So what value will `123,456` represent? How about `123.456`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support either character as a *decimal point* but not accept *thousands separators* then the easiest way is to just replace all `,` with `.` and use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
stringValue = stringValue.Replace(',','.');
double.TryParse(stringValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double doubleValue)
```

However, if a user supplies a value with a thousands separator (with or without a decimal), then this method will give wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get what you mean exactly. But here is something that can help with the Numeric format of a string:

```
double [] value = {123.456,567.1};
Console.WriteLine("Your account balance is {0:C2}.", value[0],value[1]);
Console.WriteLine("Your account balance is {1:C3}.", value[0],value[1]);
// Displays "Your account balance is $123.46."
        //  "Your account balance is $567.100."
```

where: 0 and 1 are the elements of the value array, value[0] and value[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings). 
C2 and C3 is showing in the currency format with two and three digits after decimal

for details and more check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) out

Answer (score 0):

Using the regex in the line of:

```
\-?[0-9]+[\.\,][0-9]+
```

This will allow numbers in the form of:

- 12.34
- 12,34
- -12.34
- -12,34

Then by using the `string.Replace`
it is possible to do this:

```
input = input.Replace(",", ".")
var numberFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat;
double value = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox.Text, numberFormat);
```

The number can be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "1.25";
var str2 = "1,25";

double Parse(string txt){
    return double.Parse(txt.Replace(",",".")
                           .Replace(".", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator));
}

Parse(str); // not crashing
Parse(str2); // not crashing
```